# How to insert rows to value

Tags: sql, sql-server

Have table with values

```
CREATE TABLE #tbl 
    (
       id int  identity(1,1),
       object_type int ,
       object_id nvarchar(50),
       refl nvarchar(4000)
    )
```

**refl** value have parametres like :

```
<prov><CProv><object_type>1</object_type><object_id>152</object_id></CProv></prov>
<prov><CProv><object_type>0</object_type><object_id>150</object_id></CProv></prov>
<prov><CProv><object_type>0</object_type><object_id>156</object_id></CProv></prov>
<prov><CProv><object_type>1</object_type><object_id>172</object_id></CProv></prov>
```

I want to select all data which is in refl to another value `declare @val nvarchar(4000)` .
Is it possible ? When I try `select @val = refl from #tbl` it select only last row, I want to select all rows. How do it? It must be like

```
@val = N'<prov><CProv><object_type>1</object_type><object_id>152</object_id></CProv></prov>
    <prov><CProv><object_type>0</object_type><object_id>150</object_id></CProv></prov>
    <prov><CProv><object_type>0</object_type><object_id>156</object_id></CProv></prov>
    <prov><CProv><object_type>1</object_type><object_id>172</object_id></CProv></prov>'
```

Comment: Did you mean to say there are 4 rows in your #tbl table?

Comment: @HardCoreProgrammer yes there are 4 rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
DECLARE @val NVARCHAR(4000) 
SELECT @val = COALESCE(@val + '', '') + refl
FROM #tbl

SELECT @val
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a T-SQL [split function](http://sqlhint.com/sqlserver/sqlserver/how-to/best-split-function-tsql-delimited) and then say

```
WHERE refl in IN yourSplitFunction(@val)
```